# docker-compose network_mode: "host" doesn't seem to work

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to build containers with a docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '2'

services:
     geonode:
        build: 
            context: .
        hostname: geonode
        container_name: geonode
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/geonode/
        entrypoint:
            - /usr/bin/python
        command: manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        network_mode: host
```

In my Dockerfile I run `apt-get update` after `FROM ubuntu:14.04` but it fails : `Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'`

I tried `docker run -i -t --net=host ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash` and then run `apt-get update` and it works.
So it seems to me that the network_mode in docker-compose and the `--net=host` with docker run don't work the same way.

Does somebody has an explanation?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have a similar issue with npm

Answer (score 3):

It works at least in version 3.7 when doing:

```
services:
    my-app:
        container_name: my-app
        build: 
            context: .
            network: host
        network_mode: host
        command: /app/my-app
```

The ports are obsolete as all ports are "exposed".

Comment: Thanks for this! Before this I had to reinstall Linux about once a week to resolve an issue of Docker not connecting to the internet when building an image.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you. After hours and hours of searching, I solved my problem. I hope you have the best day of your life. 
To anyone who is using a VPN or proxy with docker compose and experiencing network issues, this is the solution

Answer (score 2):

Since this answer was posted, `docker build --network` is now an option. So you can run:

```
docker build --network host -t charmosz/geonode .
```

And as of the compose file 2.2, this is an option in compose:

```
version: '2.2'

services:
  geonode:
    image: charmosz/geonode
    build:
      context: .
      network: host
    ...
```

You may be seeing a network collision with the bridge network. In that case, setting the "bip" can change the subnet used by docker for the default bridge network named bridge by setting the following in the daemon.json file:

```
{ "bip": "172.16.100.1/24" }
```

You'll need to restart docker for that change to apply. I've [presented on this recently](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2019/tips-and-tricks-of-the-captains.html#address-pools) (note the previous slides show where to configure daemon.json options in Mac and Windows).

Comment: the option `--net` doesn't seem to be present anymore

Comment: doesn't seem to be available as well at least in 1.26.2 that I have locally

Comment: How to fix the bridge network? I have to reinstall Linux every week when my container stops connecting to the internet. Now I learnt to just use 'host' as per @nice_pink answer.